# Why is my project not compiling?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-juno

[image]

I checked out a new version of my project from svn and now Java has made the easy thing difficult. I don't know what is wrong and I can't even build the project. What should be done? The code should compile, it's just not being picked up by the IDE.

[image]

And I couldn't run it with Java 7 but that might be a different question, now I can't even run it with Java 6 since Eclipse has made the easy thing difficult. Did I do something wrong when I checked out the project from svn? I use xp-dev.com

Comment: Your project root should probably be `dungeonworld`, and set the `src` directory as a source folder on the build path for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked out the entire repository instead of just one tag. You wanted to check out `trunk`.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your src directory that contains your packages and specify Build Path -> Use as source folder and it will set things up properly for you.